# How do I prevent Boolean values to be overwritten in if statement?

Tags: swift, if-statement, swift3, boolean

I'm trying to remove SKAction with key through checking the Bool value to determine state in an if statement.

The reason for this solution I'm trying to achieve is to give the end-user the ability to mute the FX sounds in the app .

**Declaring:**

```
    var mute: Bool? = false
    let popAction = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("flaps", waitForCompletion: false)
    let coinAction = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("coinSound", waitForCompletion: false)
```

**If statement to determine value before taking action and also where the issue might be since the if statement is running even if bool is true:**

```
    if !self.mute!  {
       // Run when Bool is false
       self.run(self.coinAction, withKey: "coinSound")
       print("Bool Value: '\(self.mute)'")
    }
```

Bool Value: false

**Function to remove SKAction when Bool is true:**

```
    func muteSound() -> Bool {
       self.mute = !self.mute!
       removeAction(forKey: "coinSound")
       print("Bool Value: '\(self.mute)'")
       return true
    }
```

Bool Value: True

**Run function:**

```
    muteSound()
```

*Note this function is executed through a button on the main menu.*

Would appreciate if you could take your time and see if I have missed anything or done anything that would cause this issue.

Comment: I doubt that the boolean variable is "overwritten" in the if statement. What does `print(self.mute)` print immediately before the if-statement? – And why is `mute` an optional at all?

Comment: Edited the post with the Print outcome for both parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, you have two choices

- You can unwrap your "mute" boolean like

  `var mute: Bool = false`

You don't need to add a "?" because you initialize "mute" to false (and not to nil (i extrapolate that you never assign "mute" as nil)).

- If you want to keep the "?" you must unwrap "mute" and then test it

  `if let mute = self.mute, !self.mute {
      // Run when Bool is false
      self.run(self.coinAction, withKey: "coinSound")
      print("Bool Value: '\(self.mute)'")
  }`

[image: summary]

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but I'm getting an error on the "if let mute=..." row with the following: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type , not “Bool". @4x10m

Comment: Thank you for a clear explanation. I have to do some changes in order to keep "best-practise" I guess. It worked @4x10m